# How do i return IEnumerable<T> from a method

Tags: c#, class, generics, collections, interface

I am developing Interface for a sample project i wanted it to be as generic as possible so i created a interface like below

```
public interface IUserFactory
{    
    IEnumerable<Users> GetAll();
    Users GetOne(int Id);
}
```

but then it happened i had to duplicate the interface to do below

```
public interface IProjectFactory
{    
    IEnumerable<Projects> GetAll(User user);
    Project GetOne(int Id);
}
```

if you looked at above difference is just types they return, so i created something like below only to find i get error `Cannot Resolve Symbol T` **What am i doing wrong**

```
public interface IFactory
{    
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetOne(int Id);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a generic [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwtft8ak.aspx)/[class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx), not just [generic methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx):

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{    
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetOne(int Id);
}
```

Defining a generic type on the interface/class ensures the type is known throughout the class (wherever the type specifier is used).

Comment: btw is this same as your anwer `public interface IFactory<Type>
{    
    IEnumerable<Type> GetAll();
    Type GetOne(int Id);
}`

Comment: @Deeptechtons - Almost. `Type` is an actual .NET class name, so this could appear ambiguous . But the name of the generic type parameter can be anything.

Answer (score 10):

Declare the type on the interface:

```
public interface IFactory<T>
```

Comment: +1 even though yours is same as Oded's, i loved his way of explaining with reference.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot infer what the T is for. You need to declare it at the class level as well.

Try:

```
 public interface IFactory<T>
 {
     IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
     T GetOne(int Id);
 }
```